# How not to lose past runs in Keras in case of outage?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

What is a good practice not to lose hours/days of training a network if something broke in the middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a custom callback that stores the last epoch, weights, loss etc to resume afterwards:

```
class StatefulCheckpoint(ModelCheckpoint):
  """Save extra checkpoint data to resume training."""
  def __init__(self, weight_file, state_file=None, **kwargs):
    """Save the state (epoch etc.) along side weights."""
    super().__init__(weight_file, **kwargs)
    self.state_f = state_file
    self.state = dict()
    if self.state_f:
      # Load the last state if any
      try:
        with open(self.state_f, 'r') as f:
          self.state = json.load(f)
        self.best = self.state['best']
      except Exception as e: # pylint: disable=broad-except
        print("Skipping last state:", e)

  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    """Saves training state as well as weights."""
    super().on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
    if self.state_f:
      state = {'epoch': epoch+1, 'best': self.best,
               'hostname': self.hostname}
      state.update(logs)
      state.update(self.params)
      with open(self.state_f, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(state, f)

  def get_last_epoch(self, initial_epoch=0):
    """Return last saved epoch if any, or return default argument."""
    return self.state.get('epoch', initial_epoch)
```

This only works if you epochs are of reasonable time, ex. 1 hour but it is clean and consistent with the Keras API.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use logging and to serialize models to disk(s) at regular intervals. You could keep the up to 5 versions of the network to avoid running out of disk memory.

Python has great [logging utilities](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html) and you might find [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pickle.html) useful to serialize your models.